# Is it required to change the "prototype.constructor" of sub class in classical inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I've been going through the following article in Mozilla JS Guide.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Examples

In the example given for **Classical inheritance with Object.create**, i'm not able to figure out why the author added the following line (line# 21):

```
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
```

Is it required for classical inheritance? Pls justify your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of ECMAScript-262 Edition 5.1, the constructor property is only set on function objects,
see *13.2 Creating Function Objects* (Step 17)

**It is never read nor used by the language itself.**

In particular,

```
obj instanceof C
```

does not use the constructor property, nor does

```
C.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj)
```

So if you do not fashion it, and you do not use a framework which uses it, you may ignore the constructor property.

For further reading, see [What’s up with the “constructor” property](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/constructor-property.html)